# phpseclib of how to get PID and kill

Tags: tomcat, ssh-keys, phpseclib

Normally i restart tomcat by entering the command on the putty.My problem tomcat always hang.Below is the step
  1. ps aux | grep tomcat
  2. Get PID
  3. Kill PID 
  cd /usr/local/tomcat/bin
  4../startup.sh

and now plan to make it auto but then how to add in the script below.

```
 $ssh = new Net_SSH2('172.16.2.96');
 if (!$ssh->login('root', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
//Line here
echo $ssh->exec('service tomcat start');
```

really appreciate your help.thank you

Comment: what hangs. The Tomcat? Or the restart command? Why do you code this in PHP? Why don't you use PLink?

Comment: Tomcat hang..just heard PLink from you.